# How to return place name from Yahoo YQL result XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, yql

I want to return **all** "name" values from the requested Yahoo YQL result, but all I get is an empty page :( This is my code so far:

```
$input = $_GET['str'];
$yql = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%20='".$input."'";

$feed = file_get_contents($yql);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($feed);

echo $xml->query->results->place->name;
```

How can I parse and return all the XML values with the name "name"?

Returned XML structure sample: [sample](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text=%27york%27)

Thank you very much for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already got the required values to query on yahoo yql, to get the values, since this is a query, it yielded many results. You need to loop it because it returned multiple results.

Consider this example: (**York** as an example.)

```
$input = 'york';
$yql = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%20='".$input."'";
$contents = file_get_contents($yql);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($contents);
$places = array();
foreach($xml->results->place as $key => $item) {
    $country_info = $item->country->attributes();
    $places[] = array(
        'placeTypeName' => (string) $item->placeTypeName,
        'name' => (string) $item->name,
        'country' => array(
            'code' => (string) $country_info['code'],
            'type' =>(string)  $country_info['type'],
            'woeid' => (string) $country_info['woeid'],
        ),
    );
}

print_r($places);
```

All the values of `name` are inside `$places`:

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2BG3pe)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! :) My last question: how can I access this way the country code (<country code="UY" type="Country" woeid="23424979">Uruguay</country> --> "UY") and the latitude and longitude values in the centroid section? It seems that the attributes are lost with the json_decode :(

Comment: @VORiAND they are not necessarily missing :) , you can check the edit